# How to screenshot particular part of the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I used the below script for screenshot of the webpage and i am successful in getting the entire webpage as a screenshot but i want only particular section of the webpage to be captured, So can you suggest me what are the changes to be done in the code.

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>  and 

       function canvas(){
        html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
       },
      width: 1200,
     height:700
    })};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first parameter of the `html2canvas` to point to the DOM element you want to copy.

Right now your are pointing it to `<body>` hence `document.body`.

You can select a `div` with a specific `id` by typing:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById( "the_id_of_the_element" ), {...}...
```

So the first parameter you give it, is the element it is going to focus on.
If you also use jQuery you could do:

```
html2canvas( $('.class_of_element'), {...}...
```

The documentation:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html